# Converting Python tuple to C#

Tags: python, c#, namedtuple

I am in the process of converting a program from Python to C#. I'm about 80% there, but I came across this code in Python and I am not sure exactly how this would translate over to C#:

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class Mode(NamedTuple):
    inh: int = None
    inh_sz: int = 0
    imm: int = None
    imm_sz: int = 0
    dir: int = None
    dir_sz: int = 0
    ind: int = None
    ind_sz: int = 0
    ext: int = None
    ext_sz: int = 0
    rel: int = None
    rel_sz: int = 0
```

It appears to be a class that inherits from the Python `NamedTuple` class. Any guidance on how this would translate over to C# would be appreciated.

Comment: What specifically are you having trouble with? Those are all class variables (so `static` in c#). Since c# integers aren't nullable, you'd have to default the `None`s to `0` or make them `int?`s

Comment: Have you looked at the C# tuple types (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples).  Initially, there was an tuple type that simply used `item1`, `item2`, etc.  Then there was a named tuple type.  Now there are tuples built into the language

Comment: @PranavHosangadi - I guess what's throwing me is that the class is inheriting from `NamedTuple`. Does this add extra functionality that I need to be aware of? Or can I simply create a class with those properties?

Comment: AFAIK you can access items in a NamedTuple by their names _and_ by their indices, like `nt.item0` or `nt[0]`. https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple https://towardsdatascience.com/understand-how-to-use-namedtuple-and-dataclass-in-python-e82e535c3691

Comment: Oh, and it's immutable so you can't change it after it's been defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you *can* [use tuples in C# 7.0 or later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples), the more traditional way of writing a class like `Mode` in C# is to just use a normal `class` with a [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) for each “tuple” item.

If it's important that you be able to access a `Mode` object's properties by index *or* by name, as you can with Python's named tuples, then you can add an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/) to the class.